# How do I calculate song popularity based on MusicBrainz ID?

Tags: api, sorting, musicbrainz

So I have 3 things for each song:

```
Name

Artist

MusicBrainz ID
```

How do I sort them by popularity?
What service can I use to match a song with it's 'stats'?

I was thinking of using YouTube, but I'm worried I'll get irrelevant results like parodies or lyrics videos etc.

Is there any popular service (with active `API/Java library`) that I can use to get vital stats of a song (`plays, hits, votes, likes, shares`) whatever?

Comment: iTunes downloads? last.fm scrobbles?

Comment: iTunes does not make number of downloads publicly available. Last.fm API does not seem to have a method to get scrobbles or plays or listeners.

Answer (score 3):

So what I did was use [Last.fm web API](http://www.last.fm/api) that returned XML responses and parse the response with JDOM. The problem is, that it's taking a lot of time.

I first use `Tag.getTopTracks()` to get top tracks for 4 tags, then I go over each track using `Track.getInfo()` and download the stats. I takes about 14 seconds to process 4 tags with 5 results each.

I'll try to fix that later, but this problem is solved for now.

Answer (score 1):

[soundcloud api](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference)

Soundcloud.com is very popular and its API is easy to use. It provides both XML and JSON format response. As far as I can tell, its API rate limit is quite high.

Here is a sample of list of stats you could get:

> "playback_count": 105068,
>   "download_count": 6694,
>   "favoritings_count": 739,
>   "comment_count": 153,